# Grep and Egrep options

Tags: regex

When I use grep -ow it affects the regex so I'm wondering what the regex would be without these options

I know that:

-o means show the line that matches the pattern

-w select lines that only match whole words

I'd like to convert egrep -ow '[1-9][0-9][0-9]+' text

egrep '[1-9][0-9][0-9]+' text but this regex is wrong with no options

Comment: `egrep` is deprecated use `grep -E` instead

Comment: The `-o` option would be better described as 'show only the matching text', not the complete line (with the consequence that if the pattern appears several times on a single line of input, you will get several lines of output for that one line of input).  Also, both the `-o` and the `-w` options are extensions compared with POSIX `grep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add word boundary.

```
egrep -o '\b[1-9][0-9][0-9]+\b' file
```

**OR**

Since egrep is depreciated, it's better to use `grep` with `-E` parameter.

```
grep -Eo '\b[1-9][0-9][0-9]+\b' file
```

Comment: what about if i remove -o?

Comment: Do i use '\w' if i remove -o?

Comment: if you remove `-o`, it would print the whole line instead of a match.

Comment: I think you should not mention `egrep` since it is deprecated

Comment: So is there a way I can include in the regex to print the match? Without option o?

Comment: Yes, I am just using egrep to learn what is the difference between grep and now I know.

Comment: Judging from the response time, there isn't a way to apply in the regex to print only matches instead of using -o? I am just curious because I am new to regex trying to get an understanding of some things.

Comment: no, it's not possible with grep to print only the match through regex only. Grep by default prints the whole line when it finds a match.